# split string test="tets" by regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to split the following string in sql:

```
select regexp_substr('version="100104" name="Contracts Ref." desc="" type="picker" bp_name="Contracts"','[^" ]+', 1, level) 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('version="100104" name="Contracts Ref." desc="" type="picker" bp_name="Contracts"','[^" ]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

but it is splitting by space.
I need a return like
`version="100104`
`name="Contracts Ref."`
can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this:

```
select regexp_substr('version="100104" name="Contracts Ref." desc="" type="picker" bp_name="Contracts"','(\w+=\"[^\"]*\")', 1, level) 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('version="100104" name="Contracts Ref." desc="" type="picker" bp_name="Contracts"','(\w+=\"[^\"]*\")', 1, level) is not null;
```

In the new regex pattern `(\w+=\"[^\"]*\")` -

`\w+=\"` Finds 1 or more occurrences of a letter or number, followed by ="

`[^\"]` Finds everything after the first quote that isn't a quote itself

`\"` Finally we get the last quote.

Comment: thank you, this is what I was trying to reach, a lot of thanks for the explaining